# Properly creating a dropdownlistfor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a simple DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC using Razor, but it seems that I do not understand properly how it works. I'm using Entity Framework to pull data from database, in my Controller method it looks like this:

```
using (var entity = new DatabaseEntities())
{
      ViewBag.CityList = entity.city.ToList();
      return View();
}
```

I'm adding values to another table, my view looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.id_city, new SelectList(@ViewBag.CityList,"id_city","city1"),"Wybierz miasto", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

With my models looking like:

**City model**

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Required]
public int id_city { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Podaj prawidlowy kod pocztowy")]
public string postcode { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Podaj prawidlowa nazwe miejscowosci")]
public string city1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<student> student { get; set; }
etc.
```

**Student model (only the important data, which does not work)**

```
[ForeignKey("city")]
public int id_city { get; set; }
public virtual city city { get; set; }
```

Right now I have ArgumentNullException thrown, which tells me that

> Value cannot be null. Name of parameter: items in System.Web.Mvc

I just want to add to Student model a value from existing rows in City database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check that, are you getting any data from city table or null?

Comment: @shahim reza, null

Comment: What is the model in that view? Are you trying to select a city for a student?) You need to show the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

If you get null then you should send empty string. May be that solve your problem.